# Need help in parsing soap webservice in android

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, ksoap2, soap-client

How can i call a soap service with request envelope in android. Im getting SockettimeoutException.
Endpoint: e1jas01.domain.cssus.com:8091/DV910/AddressBookManager?WSDL

```
//Soap Request...

    <Envelope>
   <Body>
      <getAddressBookV2Element>
        <Entity>
            <EntityId>9</EntityId>
         </Entity>
      </getAddressBookV2Element>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

//Android Code...
//Below the method which i have tried.

```
public void callWebservice()
{
    private final String NAMESPACE1 = "http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP010000/";
    private final String URL1 = "https://e1jas01.domain.cssus.com:8091/DV910/AddressBookManager";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP010000//getAddressBookV2";

    private final String METHOD_NAME1 = "getAddressBookV2";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE1, METHOD_NAME1);
   PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
    weightProp.name = "arg0";
    weightProp.setValue("9");
    request.addProperty(weightProp);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    // create header
    Element[] header = new Element[1];
    header[0] = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Security");
    header[0].setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand","1");
    Element usernametoken = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken");
    usernametoken.setAttribute(null, "Id", "UsernameToken-1");
    header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT,usernametoken);
    Element username = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Username");
    username.addChild(Node.IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE,"Gowtham");
    usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,username);
    Element pass = new Element().createElement(null,"n0:Password");
    pass.setAttribute(null, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
    pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "Gowtham");
    usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);
    Element[] body = new Element[1];
    body[0] = new Element().createElement("http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP010000/","getAddressBookV2Element");
    Element EntityNode = new Element().createElement("http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP010000/", "Entity");
    body[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT,EntityNode);
    Element EntityIdNode = new Element().createElement("http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP010000/", "EntityId");
    EntityIdNode.addChild(Node.IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE,"9");
    EntityNode.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,EntityIdNode);

    // add header to envelope
    envelope.headerOut = header;
    envelope.bodyOut = body;
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.bodyOut = request;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try 
    {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        Log.i("myApp", response.toString());
    } 
    catch (SoapFault e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Exception Generated", ""+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also i tried adding the Propertyinfo instead of Element in Soap body, still i receive the Exception.
The same envelope works good in soapUI tool.
Can alone please help to fix this one.

Thanks, 
Gowtham.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpTransportSE.java](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-j2se/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransportSE.java) have multiple constructors.

```
/**
* Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url
*
* @param url
* the destination to POST SOAP data
* @param timeout
* timeout for connection and Read Timeouts (milliseconds)
*/
    public HttpTransportSE(String url, int timeout) {
        super(url, timeout);
    }
```

Replace your code:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

to

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60 * 1000); // 60 sec
```

Comment: After changing them i got SSLcertification  error using sslsocketfactory class.. Any idea??.